# How to take a screenshot in media3 ExoPlayer

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, exoplayer

I need to take a screenshot in ExoPlayer, the root view of which is PlayerView.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vItSF.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and found a simple solution to how to get a Bitmap from the view, partly this is the answer to my question

```
val bitmap = videoView.drawToBitmap()
```

**UPDATED 27.04.2023**

DrawToBitmap() in my case produced a black screenshot. I haven't found anything better than specifying surface_type as surfaceview

```
app:surface_type="surface_view"
```

Then in the code I convert the player view to a surface view

```
binding.apply {
val videViewSurface = videoView.videoSurfaceView as SurfaceView
ScreenshotUtils.takeScreenshotWithPixelCopy(videViewSurface) { bitmap ->...}
}
```

Then I use Pixel Copy to create the final bitmap

```
fun takeScreenshotWithPixelCopy(videoView: SurfaceView, callback: (Bitmap?) -> Unit) {
            val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                videoView.width,
                videoView.height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            try {
                val handlerThread = HandlerThread("PixelCopier")
                handlerThread.start()
                PixelCopy.request(
                    videoView, bitmap,
                    { copyResult ->
                        if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                            callback(bitmap)
                        }
                        handlerThread.quitSafely()
                    },
                    Handler(handlerThread.looper)
                )
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                callback(null)
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't the line "val videViewSurface = videoView.videoSurfaceView as SurfaceView" give ClassCastException? In my case it does and I'm not able to cast it to SurfaceView. Please let me know how to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method I use to grab screenshots of a specific `View`. You can pass the intance of `PlayerView` to the method to get the `Bitmap` of your screenshot which you can save or use accordingly.

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshotForView(View view) {
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    view.layout((int) view.getX(), (int) view.getY(), (int) view.getX() + view.getMeasuredWidth(), (int) view.getY() + view.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return bitmap;

}
```